# Powershell source alternative command

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, dotfiles

So I am more familiar with the

> source

command in linux. Usually to set my environment variables I would run the following command.

> source .env

with .env being a dot file.

How do I do this command in Powershell?

Comment: [`help about_scripts`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) specifically the section on `DOT SOURCING`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an environment file like
EnvVarFile.ps1 with setting environment variable like

```
Set-Item Env:TestEnvVar "TestEnvVarValue"
```

Run ps1 file in the powershell like

```
. ./EnvVarFile.ps1
```

Use environment variables like

```
>$Env:TestEnvVar
TestEnvVarValue
```